# Pass argument to short code function in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, parameter-passing, wordpress-shortcode

I have developed a short code function in function.php. What I want to do is pass the argument to that short code function so it will fetch data from database based on some query using that argument. I just want to know how to pass argument. Like I have used short code on WordPress page.

How can I pass name of the page or static text argument to the short code function in PHP? For the time being I am fetching data by using static argument.

My short code function is:

```
function db_short() {
    global $wpdb;
    $result = $wpdb->get_results ( "SELECT * FROM interestclass where Subject='Bakery, Pastory & Cookies' " );
}
add_shortcode( 'show_db_info', 'db_short' );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/* you must change your code to pass agrument in shortcode & fetch same argument in you function code like below */

/* **shortcode** */

[show_db_info name="text here"]

/* **function code** */
 
  
function db_short($atts) {
    
    $name = ($attr['name']!='' ? $attr['name'] : 'default value here if blank') ;  
    global $wpdb;

    $result = $wpdb->get_results ( "SELECT * FROM interestclass where Subject='Bakery, Pastory & Cookies' " );

}

   add_shortcode( 'show_db_info', 'db_short' );
```

Comment: Can we send multiple argument in short code? @wpdevloper_j

Comment: Yes, you can. read the documentation: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_shortcode/#user-contributed-notes